# my program fails when I build and succeeds when I rebuild?

Tags: c

Whenever I build my program using visual studio 2015, it says it fails, but when I rebuild immediately after, it says it succeeded. Another question is how do i store multiple inputs for SKU, price and price and then properly output it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_ITEMS 10

struct Item
{
    int sku_[10];
    int quantity_[10];
    float price_[10];
};

int main(void)
{
    int size = 0;
    int input =1;
    int i;
    int j;

    struct Item items[10];

    printf("Welcome to the Shop\n");
    printf("===================\n");
    printf("Please select from the following options\n");

    while (size <= MAX_ITEMS && input != 0)
    {
        printf("1) Display the inventory.\n2) Add to the inventory.\n0)Exit.\n); 
        printf("Select:");
        scanf_s("%d", &input);

        while (input < 0 || input >2 && input != 0)
        {
            printf("Invalid input, try again: Please select from the following); 
            printf("1)Display the inventory.\n2)Add to the inventory.\n0) Exit.\n");       
            printf("Select:");
            scanf_s("%d", &input);
        }

        if (input == 1)
        {
            printf("Inventory\n");
            printf("====================\n");
            printf("Sku    Price    Quantity\n");
            printf("%d", items[size].sku_);
        }
        else if (input == 2)
        {
            printf("Please input a SKU number:");

            if (size >= MAX_ITEMS)
            {
                printf("The inventory is full");
            }
            else if (size < MAX_ITEMS)
            {
                scanf_s("%d", &items[size].sku_);
                printf("Quantity:");
                scanf("%d", &items[size].quantity_);
                printf("Price:");
                scanf("%f", &items[size].price_);
                printf("The item is successfully added to the inventory.\n");
                size += 1;
            }
        }
        else if (input == 0)
        {
            printf("Good bye");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the errors when it fails? And don't ask different unrelated questions under the same topic.

Comment: This cannot compile *at all* much less compile on rebuild. The first `printf` in both your `while` loops have an unclosed string constants.

Comment: the posted code, when run through a compiler, outputs 'many' warning messages (an several error messages).  Please post the actual code, preferably by 'cut and paste'. One example of an error: `printf("1) Display the inventory.\n2) Add to the inventory.\n0)Exit.\n);` which is missing the trailing `"`.

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 10.  Suggest using an `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those magic numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: the function: `scanf_s()` returns an `int` that either indicates the number of successful format conversion or `EOF` if an error occurs.  When calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: strongly suggest, when checking the variable: `input` to use a `switch()` statement so each value can be easily checked and an incorrect value only needs to be found one (in the `default` case)

Comment: why output a prompt to the user to input another set of values, when the array may already be full.  Suggest checking for a full array before prompting the user for more data

Comment: to get output to the terminal to print immediately, suggest most of the calls to `printf()` contain a trailing `'\n' in the format string.

Comment: this line: `struct Item items[10];` should really be: `struct Item items[ MAX_ITEMS ];  so when `MAX_ITEMS` changes, everything else also changes.

Comment: this line: `printf("%d", items[size].sku_);` will only print one entry from the `items[]` array (rather than the complete list of filled entries)  AND when the array is full, will try to print beyond the end of the `items[]` array, resulting in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are errors detected in the source code:

1- As WhozCraig suggests, two printf() calls are bad terminated.

Instead of:

```
printf("1) Display the inventory.\n2) Add to the inventory.\n0)Exit.\n); 
...
printf("Invalid input, try again: Please select from the following);
```

Add a text terminator:

```
printf("1) Display the inventory.\n2) Add to the inventory.\n0)Exit.\n"); 
...
printf("Invalid input, try again: Please select from the following");
```

2- When entering items[size].sku_, or .quantity_, or .price_, use a pointer to a value instead of a pointer to a array of value. The struct Item is malformed.

Just modify the struct Item:

```
struct Item
{
    int sku_; // unexpected use [10];
    int quantity_; // unexpected use [10];
    float price_; // unexpected use [10];
};
```

3- When printing the inventory, use a loop and not the last index. And format all attributes of each items[i] to align with the header.

```
printf("Sku    Price    Quantity\n");
for(i=0;i<size;i++) {
    printf("%6d %8d %6.2f\n", items[i].sku_,items[i].quantity_,items[i].price_);
}
```